# PHPUnit code coverage reports SOME files as they have no code in it (and so report a 0/0 Line 100% coverage)

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I've been searching a solution for a while but couldn't find any.

I do some code-coverage on my PHP application and it works fine except for a couple of files that PHPUnit seems to consider as empty (I mean, as there was no line of code) even though they are not empty (each one contain hundreds lines).

I can see the class and its methods but each function is considered to have 0 line (it says 0/0 100% coverage). If I try to click on function or classes names, I usually see the code but not for these problematic classes.

I'd like to post an image but as I'm a new user I unfortunately can't.

Anyone got the same issue ?

Edit: Here is a sample class that has the issue:

[1 http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9127/screenshot1aig.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/9127/screenshot1aig.png)

Edit after solution found (2): I removed source code since it was not the problem.

Comment: maybe send 2 example files, one that you think "covers" the other?

Comment: I'm not sure I got the same issue, but sometimes that can happen. Changing a bit of the format can change things. You should add the files in question if you want to no more next to if you're the only one that happens this to.

Comment: +1 for a good Q and if someone else upvotes, you should be able to add screenshots

Comment: I added 2 files text (removing some code because otherwise I get to length limit for a post). One has the issue (PlayersManager) and one hasn't (SystemPropertiesManager)

Comment: If you select all your code and press CTRL-K it will indent it and format the code properly. Unfortunately, this causes you to go over the character limit on this post - you may want to either remove some irrelevant lines (difficult to know what's relevant in this situation, I know) or pick smaller files (if you have any)

Comment: @Basic, unfortunalety Those are some of the smaller files I have. Do you think the format can change something to the code coverage ?

Comment: @Icefire To be honest, I don't know but I was simply referring to the formatting of your Q on StackOverflow (I went to edit the Q to tidy it up and make it more readable but couldn't save it because of the character limit).

Comment: Yes I know, I was wondering anyway if PHPunit was sensitive to formatting. I just uploaded a screenshot if it can help you. I didn't find the solution yet even though I still write unit tests for other classes without issue.

Comment: please shrink your files until you can't shrink them no more without phpunit behaving differently. this way it's easier to find out what's actually going on, and you don't get over the limit of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround guys. I did as proposed by cweiske (which I should have done earlier) and shrinked until the phpunit code coverage would work. But surprise, it never worked even though I left only one single method.

I created another file "Foo.php", containing the same content as PlayersManager (almost empty, only one function).

An Foo.php was covered perfectly ! I copied the whole file I had from PlayersManager into Foo.php, ran the code coverage and it was working perfectly.

Just to prove I'm not crazy, I recopied the code in PlayersManager and retried: PlayersManager coverage was still 100% with 0 line of code.

I deleted PlayersManager.php and renamed Foo.php PlayersManager.php, reran the coverage and it works !

Is phpunit keeping some cache or something like that !?

Anyway the workaround will make it for other problematic files in future, but just wondering !

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

for the record if someone check this thread. I had exactly the same problem using phpunit version 9.6.7

others files in the project were show correctly except one with a very long line, which was a list of ids. After some trial and error found this workaround: split the line into multiple lines.

my line was an array assignment of 500 elements, using replace with regex replaced all the "," with ",\n"

sorry for the necromancy.